# Asp.net read file .dbf error conn.Open()

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-foxpro

file dbf: C:\myTable.dbf;
code:

```
var file = @" C:\myTable.dbf";
var connectionString = @"Provider=vfpoledb;Data Source=" + file + ";Collating Sequence=machine;";
OdbcConnection conn = new OdbcConnection(connectionString);
conn.Open();

ERROR [IM002] [Microsoft][ODBC Driver Manager] Data source name not found and no default driver specified
```

Comment: Something seems wrong in your connection string. Look at these examples - ODBC - http://www.connectionstrings.com/microsoft-visual-foxpro-odbc-driver/

Comment: I'm pretty sure "Collating Sequence" isn't the right string. Try just "Collate" there.

Answer (score 1):

Can you Please try changing connection string provider

try
         {
         string conString = "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=c:\ZIP.DBF;Extended Properties=dBase IV";
         OleDbConnection conn = new OleDbConnection ( conString );
         command = conn . CreateCommand ( );

```
     // create the DataSet
     DataSet ds = new DataSet ( );
     dataGridView1 . DataSource = null;

     // open the connection
     conn . Open ( );
     string commandString = "Select * from  ZIP.DBF";
     // run the query
     command . CommandText = commandString;
     OleDbDataAdapter adapter = new OleDbDataAdapter ( command );
     adapter . Fill ( ds );

     // close the connection
     conn . Close ( );

     // set the grid's data source
     dataGridView1 . DataSource = ds . Tables [ 0 ];
     }
 catch ( Exception ex)
     {
     MessageBox . Show (  ex . Message );

     }
```

Comment: debug: conn.Open() --> Error: C:\myTable.dbf is not a valid path.  Make sure that the path name is spelled correctly and that you are connected to the server on which the file resides.

Comment: you can put your dbf file on the other location than the c drive as on c drive have some permission issue also. and change the path in the connection string. Thank you.